# How to use a defined local IP instead of external one

Tags: networking, ip, route

I have a Gentoo Linux server.
Server is connected to two networks: internal and external.

```
Internal network ip: 192.168.1.200
External network ip: 192.168.0.2
```

If I'm trying to make request from server to itself, it uses external network IP.
Connecting to nginx using Wget gives me this log record:

```
server ~ # tail -n 1 /var/log/nginx/error_log
192.168.0.2 - - [27/Aug/2014:19:04:42 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "-" "Wget/1.14 (linux-gnu)"
```

Despite that I connecting directly to 192.168.1.200:

```
server ~ # wget http://192.168.1.200/
```

Routing table (metric is higher on external network, but seems ignored):
**ip route show**

```
server ~ # ip route
192.168.0.0/30 dev wan  scope link  metric 20 
192.168.1.0/24 dev lan  scope link  metric 10
```

**ip route get**:

```
server ~ # ip route get 192.168.1.200
local 192.168.1.200 dev lo  src 192.168.1.200 
    cache <local>
```

How can I get this machine to connect using 192.168.1.200 to itself, instead of 192.168.0.2?

Comment: Do you have any iptables rules? `iptables -t nat -nvL`. If you've got a MASQUERADE or SNAT rule that is too broad, that can cause this.

Comment: You saved my day! Thank you vm. I completely forgot that I'm behind NAT'ed network. Sorted this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned by @Patrick in one of the comments to my question, I was encountering an issue with my `iptables` NAT rules.

- **eth0**: Internal network, 192.168.1.200
- **eth1**: External network, 192.168.0.2

My NAT rule was:

```
$ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

That means, that all traffic whose output destination device is not interface **eth0** will be masqueraded. The same thing happens with local traffic too, as it comes out from the **lo** interface.

After fixing `iptables` NAT rule to:

```
$ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

My problem was solved!

Comment: Local traffic can also have 127.0.0.1 (or in general, 127.0.0.0/8) as its destination.  It may be easier to masquerade based on where your packet is going, rather than where it isn't.

Comment: @Jander, you are definitely right! I need to send all traffic whose destination is not an internal or local network through NAT. Can you, please, give me a right advice on that?

Answer (score 6):

If you have this problem with every program you run, you should check your server firewall rule. Make sure that it only use `NAT` for external destination. Your route table make no sense if you have a wide `NAT` rule.

After fixing firewall rule, for `wget`, you can use `--bind-address` option to chose what interface you want to use:

```
wget --bind-address=192.168.1.200 http://192.168.1.200/
```

From [wget documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Download-Options):

> ‘--bind-address=ADDRESS’
>
> When making client TCP/IP connections, bind to ADDRESS on the local
>   machine. ADDRESS may be specified as a hostname or IP address. This
>   option can be useful if your machine is bound to multiple IPs.

You can use a [.wgetrc](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Startup-File) file to make this permanent.

Comment: Good point, thanks. But I have problems with EVERY program I use, not only wget.

Comment: @Greshnik: I update answer with a more details. If you can give use your firewall rule, we can make it clearly.